# Selectable area/sentence in an image

Tags: javascript

I have a book in image files. I am writing a web application that loads the book and shows a page at a time. I wonder how to make a sentence selectable in a page and show a message. As I know, it has to something with image coordinates.

Please see http://epaper.dawn.com/ in which a news is selectable. I want only sentence selectable in a image and show some message. What should I do to achive this? Thanks.

Comment: Google OCR .net and go from there.

Comment: I do not want to recognise characters. I just want to select an area on an image like the example website above.

Comment: @JeevanJose - say what? Please have a look at this link: http://epaper.dawn.com/2013/08/01/pages/01_08_2013_001.jpg The page is using an image-map. It's pretty easy to make a html tool that will allow a user to define their own polygons/rectangles for the same purpose. Unfortunately, it's a manual process to define each of them though - I.e minimum of 3 clicks per area - 2 for the opposite corners, 1 to add the defined rectangle to the list of polygons on the page.

Comment: @enhzflep: Any sample code will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know where to select or in other words, where the characters or the sentence are? Does the book change or is it always the same? If optical character recognition is not the solution, you need to have full information of where the text is and then you can only add e.g. transparent text above it for selecting, because it is not possible to select any text from a rasterized image.

If you have all of the information separate to the image you can place each character on top of the original with HTML and CSS. You need to place each character exactly on top of the image in correct places.

The dragons on the way are:

1. You need to rely most likely on absolute positioning, which requires tedious work and might break copying and pasting in some contexts where the receiving end isn't able to remove those (copying often copies the included style) or
2. You need to use exactly same font with same spacing, kerning, justification, line height and so forth - which essentially renders the idea of displaying a raster image useless as you would have a digital copy of it anyway

The more options for selecting you wish to provide and more alternatives for characters, sentences, paragraphs, pages you have, the more difficult it will become.

Comment: I intend to store coordinates in a text/xml file for each page. That will be manual work. I just want to see some sample source code to know how exactly image with cordinates works... Need some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I posed for another question of a similar nature some time back.
You need to click on the 2nd image to define the points - opposite corners for rectangles, or consecutive points in either a clock-wise or anti-clockwise direction for the polygons, before clicking the corresponding button to add either a rect or a polygon to the image-map.

You can then hover over the corresponding area in the first image to see the area outlined and highlighted.

It's rather rough and offers no error-checking, but demonstrates the principle nonetheless. Tested with Chrome.

Hope it's of some use to you. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var canvas, hdc, markerImg;
var curPoints;

function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

function canvasClick2(e)
{
    e = e || event;

    var x, y;

    x = e.offsetX;
    y = e.offsetY;

    curPoints.push(x);
    curPoints.push(y);

    hdc.drawImage(markerImg, x- markerImg.width/2, y-markerImg.height/2);

    n = curPoints.length;
    var str = ''
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
            str += ', ';
        str += curPoints[i];
    }
    byId('coords').innerHTML = str;
}

function myInit()
{
    curPoints = new Array();
    canvas = byId('canvas1');
    hdc = canvas.getContext('2d');
    markerImg = new Image();

    // just a 5x5 pixel image of a '+' symbol - a cross-hair.
    markerImg.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHklEQVQIW2NkQID/QCYjiAsmoABFEMRBAThVYmgHAAhoBQWHhfyYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";

    canvas.addEventListener('click', canvasClick2, false);

    var img = byId('img1');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', img.width);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', img.height);
//  canvas.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/gladiators.png)';
    canvas.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw5pL.png)';


    var x,y, w,h;

    // get it's position and width+height
    x = img.offsetLeft;
    y = img.offsetTop;
    w = img.clientWidth;
    h = img.clientHeight;

    // move the canvas, so it's contained by the same parent as the image
    var imgParent = img.parentNode;
    var can = byId('canvas2');
    imgParent.appendChild(can);

    // place the canvas in front of the image
    can.style.zIndex = 1;

    // position it over the image
    can.style.left = x+'px';
    can.style.top = y+'px';

    // make same size as the image
    can.setAttribute('width', w+'px');
    can.setAttribute('height', h+'px');

    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
}

function myClear()
{
    hdc.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    curPoints.length = 0;
    byId('coords').innerHTML = '';
}

function myAddShapePoly()
{
    var src, tgt = byId('imgMap1'), coordStr;

    src = byId('coords');
    coordStr = src.innerHTML;

    var newArea = document.createElement('area');
    newArea.setAttribute('shape', 'polygon');
    newArea.setAttribute('coords', coordStr);
    newArea.setAttribute('title', 'polygon');

    newArea.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("poly area clicked");');

    newArea.onmouseout = myLeave;
    newArea.onmouseover = function(){myHover2(this);};

    tgt.appendChild(newArea);
    myClear();
}

function myAddShapeRect()
{
    var src, tgt = byId('imgMap1'), coordStr;

    src = byId('coords');
    coordStr = src.innerHTML;

    var newArea = document.createElement('area');
    newArea.setAttribute('shape', 'rect');
    newArea.setAttribute('coords', coordStr);
    newArea.setAttribute('title', 'rect');

    newArea.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("rect area clicked");');

    newArea.onmouseout = myLeave;
    newArea.onmouseover = function(){myHover2(this);};

    tgt.appendChild(newArea);
    myClear();
}



function myHover2(element)
{
    var hoveredElement = element;
    var coordStr = element.getAttribute('coords');
    var areaType = element.getAttribute('shape');

    switch (areaType)
    {
        case 'polygon':
        case 'poly':
            fillPoly(coordStr);
            break;

        case 'rect':
            fillRect(coordStr);
    }
//  byId('img1').style.cursor = 'pointer';
}


function myLeave()
{
    var canvas = byId('canvas2');
    var hdc = canvas.getContext('2d');
    hdc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
//  byId('img1').style.cursor = '';
}


function fillRect(coOrdStr)
{
    var canvas = byId('canvas2');
    var hdc = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var mCoords = coOrdStr.split(',');
    var top, left, bot, right;
    left = mCoords[0];
    top = mCoords[1];
    right = mCoords[2];
    bot = mCoords[3];
    var canvas = byId('myCanvas');
    var tmp = hdc.fillStyle;

    hdc.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.3);";
    hdc.fillRect(left,top,right-left,bot-top);
    hdc.strokeRect(left,top,right-left,bot-top);
    hdc.fillStyle = tmp;
}
// takes a string that contains coords eg - "227,307,261,309, 339,354, 328,371, 240,331"
// draws a line from each co-ord pair to the next - assumes starting point needs to be repeated as ending point.
function fillPoly(coOrdStr)
{
    var mCoords = coOrdStr.split(',');
    var i, n;
    n = mCoords.length;
    var canvas = byId('canvas2');
    var hdc = canvas.getContext('2d');

    hdc.beginPath();
    hdc.moveTo(mCoords[0], mCoords[1]);
    for (i=2; i<n; i+=2)
    {
        hdc.lineTo(mCoords[i], mCoords[i+1]);
    }
    hdc.lineTo(mCoords[0], mCoords[1]);

    tmp=hdc.fillStyle;
    hdc.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.3);";
    hdc.stroke();
    hdc.fill();
    hdc.fillStyle = tmp;
}

</script>
<style>
body
{
    background-color: gray;
}

#canvas1
{
    cursor: crosshair;
}
#canvas2
{
    pointer-events: none;       /* make the canvas transparent to the mouse - needed since canvas is position infront of image */
    position: absolute;
}
.heading
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload='myInit();'>
    <div align='center'>
        <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw5pL.png' id='img1' usemap='#imgMap1'/>
            <map name='imgMap1' id='imgMap1'>
            </map>
        <canvas id='canvas2'></canvas>

        <canvas id='canvas1' width='200' height='200'></canvas>
        <br>
        <input type='button' onclick='myClear();' value='clear'/>
        <input type='button' onclick='myAddShapePoly();' value='addPolygon (3+ points)'/>
        <input type='button' onclick='myAddShapeRect();' value='addRect (2 points)'/>
        <br>
        <span id='coords'></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```